# Access FTP over http link

Tags: networking, ftp, http

I am using a program that when you type a link in it auto puts http:// at the start yet I want it to direct to my ftp server, how do you do this?

EDIT:
I do own the ftp server and am just using the built-in Windows internet information services manager. I would rather use a kinda of ftp > http converter and keep anonymous access.

Comment: Do you control the web server (and what is it)?

Comment: If you want to implement *"ftp > http converter"* (though it looks like you actually want *"http > ftp converter"*), then you should have asked that question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't force a program to do something that it doesn't allow you without modifying the program.

FTP and HTTP are different protocols.  If your program sends FTP commands to a server expecting HTTP commands, it won't work.

You may need to run your own HTTP server that's pointed at the same files your FTP server is serving.